# The request to create a scratch org failed with error code: VR-0003

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, preview

I am trying to create a `Scratch Org` with a `Release` of `Preview`.

This is the `project-scratch-def.json` file:

```
{
  "orgName": "Winter 23 Preview Org",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "release": "Preview",
  "features": ["EnableSetPasswordInApi"],
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    }
  }
}
```

When I use `VSCode` to create a default scratch org, I get this error:

> The request to create a scratch org failed with error code: VR-0003.

The `Dev Hub` is on version `Summer '22 Patch 18.16`

According to the documentation:

- [Select the Salesforce Release for a Scratch Org](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_version_selection.htm)

The `Winter ’23` preview end date is `October 15, 2022`

Why won't it let me create a `Preview` scratch org?

Comment: Hey @robs, I had a very similar experience, and am now again getting this trying to get a Spring 23 release scratch org. Would you mind letting me know if you're able to create spring orgs yet?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment I was also experiencing this for Winter 23 and Spring 23. I raised a case to SF support and it has now been resolved.

It seems some "internal Instance Mapping table" was missing entries. SF support have now added these and my Preview scratch instances are working.

Response from support

> We have added UMEA instances in Spring'23 to Scratch/Sign-Up routing
> internally our internal Instance Mapping table

Posting here in case anyone else runs into this.

Answer (score 1):

I changed nothing, and 2 days later, it worked fine.